# Product Verification System

Tags: authentication, physical, deletion

I'm thinking about a system that will allow my end users to verify their products with the manufacture key/imei number.

I'm planning to check that key against my information saved in server and let the user know if his product is original or fake.

But the process doesn't seem secure to me, what can I do to make it secure and also make the user experience better?

Comment: You will have to define what you mean by 'secure'. Why do you feel that it is not secure? Where is the insecurity that you see? As it stands, this question is far too undefined to be able to answer.